# Calculating Diagrams with Wilson Lines to One Loop

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, s-matrix-theory, wilson-loop, relativistic-jets

I have a question concerning the calculation of amplitudes containing Wilson lines.

I want to calculate the jet function defined by equation (3.3) from this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0805.3515).

$$\mathcal{J}(\text{arguments})u_s(p)=\left<0|\Phi(\infty,0)\psi(0)|p,s\right>\tag{3.3}$$
at one loop, which, after using the LSZ formula, requires the calculation of the amplitude
$$\left<0|
\Phi(\infty,0)\psi(0)\bar\psi(x)
|0\right> =
\left<0\bigg|\mathbb{T}\bigg\{\mathbb{P}\bigg[\exp\left(
ig_s\int_0^\infty ds\ n\cdot A(sn)\right)\bigg]
\psi(0)\bar\psi(x)
\bigg\}\bigg|0\right>$$
at one loop.

To solve it, I first assume that the state $\left|0\right>$ here is not the vacuum state of the free theory, but the vacuum state of $\left|\Omega\right>$ of the interacting theory, thus
$$
\left<0|
\Phi(\infty,0)\psi(0)\bar\psi(x)
|0\right> \rightarrow 
\left<\Omega|
\Phi(\infty,0)\psi(0)\bar\psi(x)
|\Omega\right> 
$$
Then, using the interaction picture we get
$$
\left<\Omega|
\Phi(\infty,0)\psi(0)\bar\psi(x)
|\Omega\right> =\lim_{T\rightarrow-\infty(1-i\epsilon)}\frac{
\left<0\bigg|
\mathbb{T}\bigg\{\bigg(1+ig_s\int_0^\infty ds\ n\cdot A(sn)\bigg)\psi(0)\bar\psi(x)\exp\bigg(-i\int_{_T}^Tdt\ H_I(t)\bigg)
\bigg\}
\bigg|0\right>
}{
\left<0\bigg|\mathbb{T}\left\{\exp\bigg(-i\int_{_T}^Tdt\ H_I(t)\bigg)\right\}\bigg|0\right>
}
$$
The next step seems to be to transform the QCD Lagrangian to the QCD Hamiltonian and choose the interaction term that contains two fermion fields and one gluon field. Is this thinking correct? Do you have any resources that explicitly calculate amplitudes that contain Wilson lines up to one loop at least, or the calculation of jet functions? I appreciate the help. Cheers!

Comment: How I would calculate this quantity to $O(\alpha_S)$ is in position space. tree-level diagram looks like a fermion line running from $x \to 0$ with a gluon hanging off it ending at a vertex at $sn$ (which you need to integrate over). Then you have one-loop vertex corrections to this diagram, with divergences cancelled by counterterms in whatever renormalization scheme you are using. Finally, you have a diagram with two gluons connecting to the fermion line, ending at $(sn)$ and $(s'n)$, that you'll need to integrate over correctly - is this more or less what you had in mind?

Comment: ^this is the "brute force" way of doing it, I don't know if there's any nicer way (I may also just be completely on the wrong track - I have never calculated things involving wilson lines before perturbatively)